# ng-show with form condition not working on a directive template in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the directive I was wondering why the CSS is not reacting accordingly to the attributes. My ng-show is a simple boolean condition that depends if the required error of a certain input is true or not. In short what I want is while the required validation is true the take exam must be hidden until the user inputs something on the textbox

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="login-container">
            <div class="form-group">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
            </div>
            <form name="loginForm" novalidate>
                <div class="form-group">
                  Required condition -- {{ loginForm.student_code.$error.required }}
                    <!-- dasdas -- {{loginForm.student_code.$error.codeValidity  }} -->
                    <br />
                    <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" name="student_code"  ng-model="studentCode" placeholder="Enter Exam Code" required />
                    <!--<span class="errors" id="error-student-code" ng-if="loginForm.student_code.$error.codeValidity">{{ errors }}</span>-->
                </div>
            </form>
            <login-button form="loginForm"></login-button>
            <a href="register"><button class="btn btn-primary">Register</button></a>
          <!-- <br /> <strong>A message must be seen after the colon if codeValidity is true: </strong> -->
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

    app.directive('loginButton', loginButton);

    loginButton.$inject = ["$http", "$window"];

    function loginButton($http, $window){
        return {
          scope: {
              form: '='
            },
            template: '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-show="{{ !form.student_code.$error.required }}" ng-click="click()">Take Exam</button>',
            controller: function($scope){
          $scope.click = function(){
            form = $scope.form;
            form.student_code.$setValidity('codeValidity', false);
            $scope.errors = "Code is Invalid";
          };
        }
        }
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Here is the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/plpKSGBtWqQnzhL60OfJ?p=preview

Comment: While the required validation is true the take exam must be hidden until the user inputs something on the textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incorrectly trying to interpolate the variable inside the `ng-show`, but `ng-show` takes an expression.  Interpolated values aren't evaluated in time for their value to be reflected by the `ng-show` directive.  Instead, you should allow `ng-show` to evaluate the expression and interpolate it if necessary.

i.e. instead of: `ng-show="{{ !form.student_code.$error.required }}"`,

do: `ng-show="!form.student_code.$error.required"`.

Comment: Works out perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Updated Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/eAL0NLt4LQuCpy3G7S5M?p=preview) 
It works now...Check the updated plunkr.

```
 ng-show=" !form.student_code.$error.required "
```

You were making mistake in binding.

Comment: Yeah at first I did ng-show="'+ !scope.form.student_code.$error.required +'", but your solution actually is perfect